# Parent not checked when all children are checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question is already on SO. But in my case, because of the HTML structure, it's different. So I have an unordered list. I want the parent to be checked when all the children are checked. In what I have now, if the children are all not checked, and I check the last of the children, the parent gets checked. That's fine. But when all the children are checked, on page load, the parent isn't checked. What's wrong in my jquery code? Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4thzrwqb/).

This is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
var totalCheckbox = $(this).closest('ul').find('li input[type=checkbox]').length;
var checkboxChecked = $(this).closest('ul').find('li input:checked').length;
var mainCheckbox = $(this).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-title input[type=checkbox]');
if (totalCheckbox == checkboxChecked) {
    mainCheckbox.attr('checked', true);
} else {
    mainCheckbox.attr('checked', false);
}
})
});
```

Comment: share the html part

Comment: `What's wrong in my jquery code?` Nothing, except it only runs in response to a click, which doesn't happen when a page loads, obviously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's wrong in my jquery code?

Nothing, except it only runs in response to a click, which doesn't happen when a page loads, obviously

To avoid repeating code, create a function - here, in honour of the current craze, it's called `gottaCheckEmAll`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function gottaCheckEmAll() {
        var totalCheckbox = $(this).closest('ul').find('li input[type=checkbox]').length;
        var checkboxChecked = $(this).closest('ul').find('li input:checked').length;
        var mainCheckbox = $(this).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-title input[type=checkbox]');
        console.log(totalCheckbox, checkboxChecked, mainCheckbox);
        if (totalCheckbox == checkboxChecked) {
            mainCheckbox.attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            mainCheckbox.attr('checked', false);
        }
    }
    $('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]').on('click', gottaCheckEmAll);
    gottaCheckEmAll.call($('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]')[0]);
});
```

The content of the function is the body of your click event, so, it's called using .call with `this` set to any one of the checkboxes, just as if you'd clicked it

[working code](https://jsfiddle.net/4thzrwqb/6/)

the last two lines *could* be written in one like

```
gottaCheckEmAll.call($('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]').on('click', gottaCheckEmAll)[0]);
```

Not sure how readable that is though

To simplify your code, however:

```
jQuery(function() { //shorthand notation of jQuery(document).ready(
    function gottaCheckEmAll() {
        // simplify checking, just see if anything is unchecked
        var checkboxUnchecked = $(this).closest('ul').find('li :not(input:checked)').length;
        var mainCheckbox = $(this).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-title input[type=checkbox]');
        // main is checked if no subs unchecked
        // don't use .attr() here for some reason
        mainCheckbox[0].checked = !checkboxUnchecked;
    }
    gottaCheckEmAll.call($('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]').on('click', gottaCheckEmAll)[0]);
});
```

[UPDATED working code](https://jsfiddle.net/4thzrwqb/10/) with handling of parent click

Code above is

```
jQuery(function() {
    function gottaCheckEmAll() {
        console.log(this);
        var checkboxUnchecked = $(this).closest('ul').find('li :not(input:checked)').length;
        var mainCheckbox = $(this).closest('.panel-default').find('.panel-title input[type=checkbox]');
        mainCheckbox[0].checked = !checkboxUnchecked;
    }
    gottaCheckEmAll.call($('.list-group-item input[type=checkbox]').on('click', gottaCheckEmAll)[0]);
    $('input[value="Accessories"]').on('click', function() {
        var checked = this.checked;
        console.log(checked);
        $(this).closest('.panel').find('.list-group-item input').each(function(i, el) {
            el.checked = checked
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Great! In your fiddle, when the parent is checked/unchecked, all the children won't check/uncheck. What changed should be made to get this working? Sorry I'm a jquery newbie

Comment: Nice use of `.call()`, I've never seen it used around jQuery before. +1

Comment: the thing is, if I check / uncheck the parent by mistake, it stops working

Comment: @YohanBlake - your original code never dealt with clicking the parent, so I didn't ADD that code for you

Comment: yes, see edited code - there's something unusual happening when using .attr() that I don't pretend to understand